# Navigation Experimental: Stack only unique items

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with pushing elements on to the navigation stack. I use my own reducer:

```
export default function navigationReducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NAV_PUSH:
        if (state.navigationState.children[state.navigationState.index].key === (action.state && action.state.key))
        return state;

        return {...state,...{
        navigationState: StateUtils.push(state.navigationState, action.state)
      }
    };

    case NAV_POP:
        if (state.navigationState.index === 0 || state.navigationState.children.length === 1)
        return state.navigationState;
        return {...state,...{
        navigationState: StateUtils.pop(state.navigationState)
      }
    };

    case NAV_JUMP_TO_KEY:
        return {...state,...{
        navigationState: StateUtils.jumpTo(state.navigationState, action.key)
      }
    };

    case NAV_JUMP_TO_INDEX:
        return {...state,...{
        navigationState: StateUtils.jumpToIndex(state.navigationState, action.index)
      }
    };

    case NAV_RESET:
      return {...state,...{
        navigationState: StateUtils.reset(state.navigationState, [action.state],0)
      }
    };

    default:
        return state
  }
}
```

When I push an item that was already pushed before, I get an exception indicating that the navigationstack should be unique.

```
Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `NavigationAnimatedView`
```

The Navigation Library doesn't guarantee this requirement.
It makes sense that the navigation stack should only contain unique items and if it should, I would think that the library takes care of this and that this is not something I would have to manually check?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently being addressed in React Native: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7348